# Encrypt and Decrypt File Using PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, rsa

I want to decrypt file with extention .txt .docx .xlsx and .pdf from uploading file.

**encrypt.php**

```
<?php
  include "koneksi.php";
  function generateKeyPairFromFileName(){
    $config = array(
      "default_md" => "sha512",
      "private_key_bits" => 512,
      "private_key_type" => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
    );

    $keypair = openssl_pkey_new($config);

    if (!$keypair) {
      die("Failed to generate key pair");
    }

    openssl_pkey_export($keypair, $privateKey, null, $config);
    $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($keypair);
    $publicKey = $publicKey['key'];

    return array(
      'publicKey' => $publicKey,
      'privateKey' => $privateKey
    );
  }

  function savePublicKeyToLocal($publicKey, $fileName) {
    $publicKeyPath = $fileName . '_public_key.pem'; // Ganti dengan lokasi penyimpanan kunci publik Anda
    file_put_contents($publicKeyPath, $publicKey);
    return $publicKeyPath;
  }

  // Fungsi untuk menyimpan kunci pribadi ke file lokal
  function savePrivateKeyToLocal($privateKey, $fileName) {
    $privateKeyPath = $fileName . '_private_key.pem'; // Ganti dengan lokasi penyimpanan kunci pribadi Anda
    file_put_contents($privateKeyPath, $privateKey);
    return $privateKeyPath;
  }

// Fungsi untuk mengenkripsi file menggunakan AES
function encryptFile($data, $key) {
  // Buat vektor inisialisasi (IV) acak
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

  // Enkripsi data menggunakan AES-256-CBC dengan kunci dan IV yang diberikan
  $encryptedData = openssl_encrypt($data, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

  // Base64 encode hasil enkripsi
  $encryptedDataBase64 = base64_encode($encryptedData);

  // Simpan atau kirim data terenkripsi ke tempat penyimpanan atau penerima
  // echo "Data terenkripsi: " . $encryptedDataBase64;

  return $encryptedDataBase64;
}

  if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
    $uploadedFileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filetmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    // Membaca isi file
    $fileContent = file_get_contents($filetmp);

    $KeyPair = generateKeyPairFromFileName();
    
    $publicKeyPath = savePublicKeyToLocal($KeyPair['publicKey'], $uploadedFileName);
    $publicKeyPath = savePrivateKeyToLocal($KeyPair['privateKey'], $uploadedFileName);

    $encryptedFileContent = encryptFile($fileContent, $KeyPair['publicKey']);
    // echo $encryptedFileContent;

    $query = "INSERT INTO upload (nama_file, filedata) VALUES ('$uploadedFileName', '$encryptedFileContent')";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        echo "File berhasil diunggah dan dienkripsi.";
    } else {
        echo "Gagal mengunggah dan menyimpan file ke database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
    }


  }
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Pilih file untuk diunggah (PDF, DOCX, XLSX, TXT, maks 15 MB):
  <input type="file" name="file">
  <button name="generate" type="submit">Generate</button>
</form>
```

I save the private and public key on local. The script above is for encrypt data before save on the database.

**ecnrypt.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "koneksi.php";

// Fungsi dekripsi
function decryptFile($data, $key) {
  // Decode data terenkripsi dari base64
  $encryptedData = base64_decode($data);

  // Ambil IV dari data terenkripsi
  $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

  $decryptedData = openssl_decrypt($encryptedData, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

  // Kembalikan data yang telah didekripsi
  return $decryptedData;
}

if(isset($_GET['nama_file'])){
  // Nama file
  $fileName = $_GET['nama_file'];

  // Membaca kunci privat
  try {
    $privateKeyPath = $fileName . '_private_key.pem';
    if (!file_exists($privateKeyPath)) {
      throw new Exception("File kunci privat tidak ditemukan: " . $privateKeyPath);
    }

    $privateKey = file_get_contents($privateKeyPath);
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Gagal membaca kunci privat: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
  }

  // Mengambil data file terenkripsi dari database
  $query = "SELECT filedata FROM upload WHERE nama_file = '$fileName'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

  if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    // Dekripsi data
    $decryptedData = decryptFile($row['filedata'], $privateKey);

    // Tampilkan data yang telah didekripsi
    echo $decryptedData;
  } else {
    echo "File tidak ditemukan!";
  }
}
```

The file that i want to decrypt is empty. i mean return empty on decrypted data. is anyone have same problem ?

Expecting file with decrypted data.

Comment: You seem to perform an AES encryption with a public RSA key and an AES decryption with the private RSA key. This is completely wrong, RSA (asymmetric encryption) and AES (symmetric encryption) are entirely different algorithms with incompatible keys. AES as a symmetric algorithm uses the *same* key for encryption and decryption.

Comment: i see, which part should i change. or you have any references for this case. thank you

Comment: Apply one and the same valid AES key for AES encryption and decryption (incidentally, the same IV must also be used). If you want to send the AES key to the other side via an insecure channel, the AES key can be encrypted with RSA ([hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem)).

Comment: oke let me try, brb. thanks

Comment: (1) If you have determined to use Asymmetric encryption (which means you encrypt data by a public key and can only decrypt this data with a private key), you may use PHP functions [openssl_public_encrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php) and [openssl_private_decrypt](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-private-decrypt.php) using the public/private keys you have generated to do the job

Comment: (2) You rely on the `filename` to save your public and private key (`$fileName . '_public_key.pem'` and `$fileName . '_private_key.pem'` respectively) may soon cause you trouble, please think if a user John has uploaded a file known as "resume.docx" and then after a few days another user Mary has uploaded a file, also known as "resume.docx", what will happen ??

Comment: (3) Make sure you are using the right type of data field to store the file data , I believe you will use something like MEDIUMBLOB ?

Comment: @KenLee - Your suggestion in (1) is generally technically impossible: RSA can only encrypt small amounts of data, the size of which depends on the key size and padding (e.g. max. 245 bytes for a 2048 bits key and PKCS#1 v1.5). In no case should larger data be divided into chunks in order to encrypt them with RSA. This is unnecessarily complicated, therefore error-prone and also quite inperformant. The correct way for large data is symmetric (or hybrid) encryption.

Comment: Yes you are right definitely, but I just want to point out the **PHP functions** to be used for Asym encryption/decryption. As you have advised he may use hybrid encryption

Comment: the case is solved. I combined between RSA and AES.

Answer (score 1):

I've reviewed my PHP script, and it appears to effectively combine RSA and AES encryption for file uploads. And works for me. Thank you.

**encrypt.php**

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include "koneksi.php";
    
    // Enkripsi
    if(isset($_POST['generate'])){
        // Mendapatkan informasi file yang diunggah
        $uploadedFileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $uploadedFileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $uploadedFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($uploadedFileName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    
        $sql = "SELECT nama_file FROM upload WHERE nama_file='$uploadedFileName'";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $rows = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    
        if( $rows > 0) {
            return header('location:./home.php?message=error');
        }
    
        // Batasi jenis file yang diperbolehkan dan ukuran file
        $allowedTypes = array('txt', 'docx', 'pdf', 'xlsx');
        $maxFileSize = 15 * 1024 * 1024; // 15 MB dalam bytes
    
        if (in_array($uploadedFileType, $allowedTypes) && $uploadedFileSize <= $maxFileSize) {
            // Menghasilkan pasangan kunci RSA
            $rsaKey = openssl_pkey_new(array(
                'private_key_bits' => 2048,
                'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA
            ));
    
            // Mendapatkan kunci privat
            openssl_pkey_export($rsaKey, $privateKey);
    
            // Mendapatkan kunci publik
            $publicKey = openssl_pkey_get_details($rsaKey)['key'];
    
            // Menyimpan kunci dengan awalan nama file yang diunggah
            $privateKeyFileName = pathinfo($uploadedFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_private_key.pem";
            $publicKeyFileName = pathinfo($uploadedFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_public_key.pem";
    
            // echo $privateKeyFileName;
            file_put_contents('./keys/'. $privateKeyFileName, $privateKey);
            file_put_contents('./keys/'. $publicKeyFileName, $publicKey);
    
            // Menghasilkan kunci AES acak
            $aesKey = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    
            // Mengenkripsi kunci AES menggunakan kunci publik RSA
            openssl_public_encrypt($aesKey, $encAesKey, $publicKey);
    
            // Unggah file
            $uploadedFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    
            // Mengenkripsi data menggunakan AES
            $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
            $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(file_get_contents($uploadedFile), 'aes-128-cbc', $aesKey, 0, $iv);
    
            // Menyimpan data terenkripsi ke sebuah variabel
            $encryptedFileContent = $iv . $ciphertext;
    
            // Menyimpan kunci AES terenkripsi ke sebuah file dengan awalan nama file yang diunggah
            $encryptedAesKeyFileName = pathinfo($uploadedFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_encrypted_aes_key.bin";
            file_put_contents('./keys/'. $encryptedAesKeyFileName, $encAesKey);
    
            // Memasukkan data file terenkripsi ke dalam database
            $query = "INSERT INTO upload (nama_file, filedata, mimetype) 
                      VALUES ('$uploadedFileName', '$encryptedFileContent', '$uploadedFileType')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
                echo "File berhasil diunggah dan dienkripsi.";
                header('location:./home.php?message=success');
            } else {
                echo "Gagal mengunggah dan menyimpan file ke database: " . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        } else {
            echo "Jenis file yang diunggah tidak diperbolehkan atau ukuran file melebihi batas maksimum.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

**decrypt.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include "koneksi.php";

if(isset($_GET['dekripsi'])) {
    $id = $_GET['dekripsi'];
    $query = "SELECT nama_file, filedata FROM upload WHERE id_file='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $uploadedFileName = $row['nama_file'];

    // Load RSA private key
    $privateKeyFileName = pathinfo($uploadedFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_private_key.pem";
    $privateKey = file_get_contents('./keys/'. $privateKeyFileName);

    // Decrypt AES key using RSA private key
    $encryptedAesKeyFileName = pathinfo($uploadedFileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . "_encrypted_aes_key.bin";
    $encAesKey = file_get_contents('./keys/'. $encryptedAesKeyFileName);
    openssl_private_decrypt($encAesKey, $decAesKey, $privateKey);

    // Load encrypted data from the database (Assuming you have a function to retrieve data from the database)
    
    $encryptedData = $row['filedata'];

    // Decrypt data using AES
    $iv = substr($encryptedData, 0, 16);
    $ciphertext = substr($encryptedData, 16);
    $plaintext = openssl_decrypt($ciphertext, 'aes-128-cbc', $decAesKey, 0, $iv);

    // Prepare file for download
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . basename($uploadedFileName));
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . strlen($plaintext));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    echo $plaintext;
    // exit;
} else {
    echo "File name not provided.";
}
?>
```

Comment: Great to know that you have used `openssl_public_encrypt` and `openssl_private_decrypt` functions to solve your problem